# Получить строку из onActivityResult

Tags: android, строки

Задача:

выбрать файл mp3 и проиграть его в приложении.

Вызываю активити, выбираю файл, в

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

приходят такие данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как теперь выдернуть путь к файлу, чтоб можно было подставить его в PlaySound?
Пробовал так, ничего  не получается

```
String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("uriString");
//Uri filePath = Uri.parse(str);
String Uri = data.getStringExtra("mData");
String name = data.getStringExtra("uriString");
```

Comment: `Uri uri = data.getData();` - дальше скармливаем этот `uri` медиа плееру (не знаю что там у вас за `PlaySound` - конкретнее не подскажу как к нему применить).

Comment: Немножко не повопросу, но вот когда мне было нужно похожее, я начал делать сам, а потом просто воспользовался готовой библиотекой, и время и с экономите и работает стабильнее. Если же ваша цель научиться это делать, сдесь же можно поссмотреть: https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/android-ringtone-picker

Comment: @woesss, спасибо, прокатило.

Comment: @Valeriy, тебе тоже спасибо, но мне нужно как попроще )